# WPF window maximize

Tags: wpf, vb.net

On my WPF window, I have set

```
me.Width = "300"  me.Height = "300"
```

When I maximize the window, the property Width and Height always have the same values (300).

How do I get the new values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for [me.ActualWidth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [me.ActualHeight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualheight(v=vs.110).aspx)